# Why do e.values[] on formSubmitReply in Google Apps script has NaN?

Tags: google-apps-script, nan, google-sheets-api, google-forms, google-apps-for-education

I am trying to make a simple tool which stores ticket number and some details that are handovered to other team members. In that process i used a Form to submit a handover and store in Google Spreasheet. But i also want to notify the team members, so i wrote a script as below.

```
function formSubmitReply(e) 
{

var timeStamp = e.values[0];
var sendTo = e.values[1];
var ticket = e.values[2];
var description = e.values[3];
MailApp.sendEmail(sendTo,
                  "New Handover",
                  + ticket +" handovered to you at "+ timeStamp +"\n\nDescription:"+ description +
                  "\n\nKindly check it using the below link\n\nhttp://goo.gl/p16qdN",
                   {name:"Handover Mail"});

}
```

In the above code e.values[2] has the ticket number through form and in forms i have used a textbox with a regex validation [c.i][r,n][q,c] which means the first three words should be C/I,R/N/Q/C. for eg CRQ, IRC, INC..etc. Everything was working alright but suddenly one day NaN starting coming in the notification mail(below output). Details in Spreadsheet is fine.

```
NaN handovered to you at 12/4/2014 12:48:23

Description:Device Check after 4 hours

Kindly check it using the below link

http://goo.gl/p16qdN
```

The above is my primary issue that i want to solve. But also as a add on i need some advice or guide on how to set some value on a cell in spreadsheet which has a fixed column and variable row when a handover is submitted. I am referring http://goo.gl/wkD0Y7 for my work. But in that `sheet.getRange(lastRow, getColIndexByName("Status")).setValue("New");` does not seem to work throwing some reference error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error may have to do with the preceding "+" sign in the email body string and the GAS compiler interpreting the string as a number. Try this code instead:

```
function formSubmitReply(e){
   var timeStamp = e.values[0];
   var sendTo = e.values[1];
   var ticket = e.values[2];
   var description = e.values[3];

   MailApp.sendEmail(
      sendTo,
      "New Handover",
         ticket + " handovered to you at " + 
         timeStamp + "\n\nDescription:" + 
         description + "\n\nKindly check it using the below link\n\nhttp://goo.gl/p16qdN",
       {name:"Handover Mail"}
   );
}
```

As for your other question, there's no built-in getColIndexByName() method, so you'll either need to copy over the function from the tutorial you referenced or just set it manually like this:

```
var statusCol = 1;
sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, statusCol).setValue("New");
```